# How the inject a Vue.component into the DOM dynamically with Proxy.render also not reading this or $t

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
const component = Vue.component('add-new-channel', {
  template: '<div class="add-new-channel"> <a-go-to-add-channel/></div>',
  components: { AGoToAddChannel }
});
const mounted = new component().$mount();
const $element = mounted.$el;
this.$nextTick(() => {
  const listEl = this.$refs.parent.querySelector('.tabs li:last-child');
  if (listEl) {
    listEl.appendChild($element);
  }
});
```

I am attempting to generate a component on the fly and inject into the page with vue 2.

The html generated uses another vue component.

The genetated content will be injected into a 3rd party lib that does not offer a slot where i need it.

Is this possible and if so how? Cannot see anything in the docs on this topic

> question updated from 1st comment below from

The above works if it is pre-built, imported and then used. However, as the app is using i18n when it attempts to mount it complains as it cannot find _t:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined
    at Proxy.Vue.$t (vue-i18n.esm.js?a925:236)
    at Proxy.render (AGoToAddChannel.vue?08f5:14)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3569)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4081)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4570)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4326)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1989)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1915)
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but, IIRC, what you want is `.$mount()` without parameters. That will mount it to an off-document element and return that element.

Comment: Ahh gotcha - almost worked but `You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount

Comment: Comps aren't supposed to be instantiated directly. Use `new Vue...`.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks! Full working solution in the answer below from you tip

Comment: FWIW, you also need to keep instance reference for unmount.

Comment: Ah yes good point thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
     this.addDynamicThing();
  });
}

addDynamicThing(){
     // Find the target element using refs and inject a new li el
     // (specific to my solution, could be any element)
     const listEl = this.$refs.parent.querySelector('.tabs ul');
     const li = document.createElement('li');
     li.onclick = (e) => e.preventDefault();
     listEl?.appendChild(li);
    
     // Instantiate a new vue instance and inject the required 
     // dependencies for the component then mount it to the target element
     this.dynamicThing = new Vue({
       i18n,
       router,
       render: (h) => h(AGoToAddChannel),
     });
     this.dynamicThing.$mount(li);
}

removeDynamicThing(){

    this.dynamicThing.$destroy();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert the component into your existing Vue 2 application, you have to pass in the parent component when calling `new Component()`:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

// I'm using script setup, you might be able to just replace this with `this` in option API components.
const parent = getCurrentInstance().proxy

const Component = Vue.component('MyComponent', MyComponent)
const myComponentInstance = new Component({
  parent, // <- This sets the current component as a parent, so that things like $t work (through inheritance)
  propsData: { // Set any props you like here
    foo: 'bar',
  },
})

// Now we have to mount the component and add it to the dom.
// There are multiple ways of doing it, this is just an example.
// You could also mount it to an element you've created with document.createElement('div')
const mountPoint = document.querySelector('#whateverYouWant')
const mountedComponent = myComponentInstance.$mount()
mountPoint.appendChild(mountedComponent.$el)
```

This will properly mount the component into the existing Vue 2 application, which let's it access everything you've registered globally, and also let's you use the vue devtools to inspect it.